# sed find and replace a string with spaces

Tags: regex, linux, bash, replace, sed

Having the following in a file:

```
public $password = 'XYZ';
```

I'm trying to replace the password's value with a different one, through an automated deployment process from backup files.

I have the regext that will match the string above in a file, but not much compatible with `sed`

```
(public\s\$password\s=\s'(.*)'?)
```

I also tried

```
sed -i -e "s/public\s\$password\s=\s'(.*)'/private\s\$password\s=\s'jingle'" configuration.php
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -i -e "s/public\s\$password\s=\s'\(.*\)'/private \$password = 'jingle'/" configuration.php
```

The problem was that you need to 'escape' the round brackets, and that `\s` doesn't work in the output pattern. You also had missed the final `/`.